# How to split traffic in A/A tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

While running 20 simutanious A/A tests, should each of them be allocated to 100% traffic? Or should all of them cumulatively be allocated to 100% traffic?

Comment: What is an "A/A test"?  An A/B test where A = B ?  Different groups treated the same?